# Breaking a div with display: inline; into a new line

Tags: html, css

So o basicly have a problem with my divs. There are some divs and imgs in my code, and they are put as inline so they just fit the contents. Though this might seem fine, i need the text to be UNDER the imgs, so break it into a new line. Also centering it relative to the img would be cool too. Thanks

**HTML:**

```
        <div class="people">
            <div class="matej">
                <img src="imgs/team_matej.jpg" alt="Photo of Matej Marek">
                <div class="name">Matěj Marek</div><br\>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.people .matej {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #0e1a45;
}

.people .matej .name {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #F2F2F2;
}

.people .matej img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
}
```

**Picture:**

[image]

Comment: If you don't want them to be inline, don't use inline. The inline rule should not be used as a substitute for fitting content.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply add the `<br>` tag after the `<img/>` tag you should be fine.

Note that you do not have to use `/` or `\` to exit the `<br>` tag!

New code:

```html
    <div class="people">
        <div class="matej">
            <img src="imgs/team_matej.jpg" alt="Photo of Matej Marek"><br>
            <div class="name">Matěj Marek</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Additionally, when using `<br\>` as you did, it won't work at all since `<br\>` isn't a valid tag. To exit a tag you will generally want to use a `/`.

Answer (score 0):

For your container, set [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#inline-flex) to `inline-flex` instead of `inline`, and set its [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction#column) to `column`. To center the content on the cross-axis (vertically) in each container, set [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items#center) to `center`.

```css
.people > .matej {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.people > .matej > img {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="people">
  <div class="matej">
    <img src="imgs/team_matej.jpg" alt="Photo of Matej Marek">
    <div class="name">Matěj Marek</div><br\>
  </div>
  <div class="matej">
    <img src="imgs/team_matej.jpg" alt="Photo of Matej Marek">
    <div class="name">Matěj Marek</div><br\>
  </div>
</div>
```